# when rendering as pdf some of the image type attachment is not properly displayed whereas rest are fine

Tags: apex, attachment, pdf

when rendering as pdf some of the image type attachment is not properly displayed whereas rest are fine. Please find my code here :

```
<apex:page controller="Attachments_11" renderas="pdf" >
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pageBlock id="details">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseWrapper}" var="j">
         <apex:column value="{!j.accountName}"/> 
         <apex:column >
         <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!j.attachmentId}"/>
         </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>          
</apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

can anyone point out what exaclty i'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to use a normal HTML like `<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload..."`?

Comment: Hi mast0r! still its failing to load the images inside pdf. but rest of the images are fine

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. To help narrow down the possible causes, is this a scenario that worked in Summer '14 and no longer works in Winter '15?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm). Part of your problem could be that you are using `<apex:form>`, `<apex: PageBlock>` and `<apex:pageBlockTable>` instead of HTML Tables in your code to format your PDFs. Those components are known to be unsafe for rendering PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are stored at document/static resource, Please check its saved as Public and there is a size limit for uploading an image in document and static the image shud be public.

Comment: images are stored in attachment, contenttype='image/jpeg'.The size of the attachments are like 6-10KB, almost same as the other images loaded successfully

Comment: Are read permissions set to all usesr? I mean individually if that image is accessed, i hope they have access permission